# iOS8 "No method with selector is implemented in this translation unit" when calling native Apple methods

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios8, selector

I have a subclass of UIView, and it attempts to clean up it's subviews during a reset operation using the following method call.

```
 [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

This is an Apple method, called on an Apple's UIView's property. **Why am I seeing this cryptic warning about methods with selector not implemented in translation unit?** I'm not using any Swift in the project, so there should be no need to translate anything...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
//results in warning:
No method with selector 'removeFromSuperview' is implemented in this translation unit
```

More code ([working with THPinViewController code](https://github.com/antiraum/THPinViewController)) THPinNumPadView.h file:

```
//
//  THPinNumPadView.h
//  THPinViewControllerExample
//
//  Created by Thomas Heß on 20.4.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Thomas Heß. All rights reserved.
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class THPinNumPadView;

@protocol THPinNumPadViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)pinNumPadView:(THPinNumPadView *)pinNumPadView numberTapped:(NSUInteger)number;

@end

@interface THPinNumPadView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<THPinNumPadViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hideLetters;

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<THPinNumPadViewDelegate>)delegate;

@end
```

THPinNumPadView.m file:

```
#import "THPinNumPadView.h"
#import "THPinNumButton.h"

@interface THPinNumPadView ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat hPadding;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat vPadding;

@end

@implementation THPinNumPadView

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<THPinNumPadViewDelegate>)delegate
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _hPadding = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 24.0f : 20.0f;
        _vPadding = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 19.0f : 13.0f;

        [self setupViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupViews
{
    // remove existing views
    //Compiler warning here
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    NSMutableString *vFormat = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"V:|"];
    NSMutableDictionary *rowViews = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

//... more setup code   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens while used build setting:

```
GCC_WARN_MULTIPLE_DEFINITION_TYPES_FOR_SELECTOR = YES // -Wselector
```

Just disable this build setting and issue will be resolved.

I think this issue should be fixed by Apple

Comment: That's totally wrong. This warning sometimes has false positives, but you are throwing away correct warnings as well. cbowns answer works correctly without throwing away valid warnings.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, this is a false positive warning thrown by Xcode. (See [Brent's OpenRadar for this issue](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/17806477)).

You can suppress it with a `clang pragma`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wselector"
            <#code#>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

(I have a clipboard snippet for the above and it's A+ awesome.)

Answer (score 1):

[Translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) are not related to *Swift*, they refer to inputs to the C (Objective-C in this case) compiler.

---

Anyway, I tried your code and it didn't produce the warning for me. Make sure that you `#import` your subclass header from the file you are calling this method, and make sure that you are properly subclassing `UIView` and not `NSObject`.

---

If this doesn't solve it, which file are calling this line from? Post more code, that may help to spot the problem. Also, try creating a new vanilla iOS project and calling the method in that project to see if it also triggers the warning.

Comment: I added more code. This is a UIView subclass, I checked subclassing and imports.

Comment: That's really weird. Can you try replacing `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` by `@import UIKit;`? Not sure if that'd help though.